# height-fluid columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently working on a design which involves three columns with tiles nested inside of them. Using the grid system in Bootstrap, i'm able to fit the widths and have them change fluidly, but i would like the same thing to happen for the height of the page, is there any sort of option for this?

https://postimg.org/image/3xaqengav/

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate question, already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Comment: One approach is to use flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox-based equal-height columns to your Bootstrap's grid system. This feature is already provided by the core Bootstrap. Just add `.row-eq-height` to your row's class. Here's the example : http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/